# Class-based decorator and repr() conservation

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators, repr

I was trying to have my class-based decorator keeping the `repr()` behavior of the original wrapped function (to match the way the `functools.wraps` decorator works on functions). I am using python 3.3.

First I tried functools:

```
import functools

class ClassBasedDecorator():
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn
        functools.update_wrapper(self, fn)
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fn(*args, **kwargs)

@ClassBasedDecorator
def wrapped(text):
    pass
```

But when I call `repr()` on the decorated function, I get:

```
>>> repr(wrapped)
'<__main__.ClassBasedDecorator object at 0x2d8860b6850>'
```

Very well, so I tried to customize the `__repr__` method of my decorator, which is supposed to be called by `repr()`.

Using functools again:

```
class ClassBasedDecorator():
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn
        functools.update_wrapper(
            self, fn,
            assigned=functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS + ('__repr__',)
        )
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
```

Doesn't change the output, but something interesting happens:

```
>>> repr(wrapped)
'<__main__.ClassBasedDecorator object at 0x2d8860b69d0>'
>>> wrapped.__repr__()
'<function wrapped at 0x2d8860a9710>'
```

Explicitly setting the `__repr__` method of the decorator instance has the same effect.

After a little more tests I deduced `repr(instance)` actually calls `instance.__class__.__repr__(instance)`. Thus the overriden `__repr__` method of the instance is never called.

---

So here are my questions:

- Why does `repr(instance)` call the `instance.__class__.__repr__(instance)` instead of `instance.__repr__()`? Or have I missed something else?
- How would you fully reproduce what `functools.wraps` does with function-based decorators to class-based decorators (including altering the result of `repr()` calls on the decorated function)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Special methods are [always looked up on the *type* of the instance](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup) (here the class object), not on the instance.  Otherwise a `__repr__` on a class would be used when you tried to print the representation of the class itself; `type(class).__repr__(class)` would use the correct magic method, while `class.__repr__()` would raise an exception because `self` was not provided.

Implement your own `__repr__` hooks:

```
class ClassBasedDecorator():
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn
        functools.update_wrapper(self, fn)
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.fn)
```

e.g. still copy over the `__module__`, `__name__` and `__doc__` attributes, and copy over the attributes from the function `__dict__`, but make any special methods a proxy.